# Filtering my svn repo. How to find the space hogs?

Tags: svn, svn-server

Our SVN repo has gotten quite fat and it needs to diet.
I dumped it and filtered the obvious culprits. Going through the fourth round of filters and the dump file is still morbidly obese.
Is there a way to determine which files are taking the most space?

Now, for those who might knee-jerk respond with WinDirStat / SpaceMonger, I need to reiterate that this is SVN. These are multiple copies of the same files.

Then again, looking at the /db/revs folder, it might be that simple (just with a few extra steps).

Your advice is welcome.

**UPDATE**

I found an alternate path that I believe would be relatively unique to our situation so I'll accept [Lazy Badger](https://superuser.com/users/99868/lazy-badger)'s answer.

For the curious, I sorted the /db/revs/0 folder by size since each file corresponds to its specific revision. Working down the commit log from the fattest revs, I was able to determine which binaries (despite being later deleted) were taking up all the room and filtered them out.

The repo dump shrank by %92.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Even you'll know space-hog, that you'll do? Rewrite history with |svndumfilter and *broke it*? **The Bad Idea (tm)**
2. Anyway, you can iterate over all revisions, collect changes with `svnlook changed` and filesizes with `svn filesize`... and think about it more deeply (added and deleted later objects, f.e.). Because text-diffs even in big text-files are not so bad, as changed binaries

Comment: Ordinarily, yes, you are correct on the first point, but we had folks committing large binaries to the repo.